# Using Forms within Iframes and then displaying response within iframe aswell

Tags: html, forms, iframe

For some reason, i am having problems with placing a form inside a iframe. It displays fine, with the form input areas working fine, but however when I try and send the details to the file (mail.php) in order to use the info submitted, it doesn't even send the data. It just remains as it was. Oh and i don't want the submit button outside the i frame unless i have to.

Here is the code for the iframe and the page it displays:

```
<form id="sms" name="sms" method="post" action="http://www.texteri/developers/iframe/mail.php">
<table width="200">
 <tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">From:</td>
<td align="left"><input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" /></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">To:</td>
<td align="left"><input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10a" /></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Message:</td>
<td align="left"><textarea name="message" cols="15" rows="2" id="message"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
<br>
 <tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And here is the code for the iframe itself:

```
   <iframe src="http://www.texteri.com/developers/iframe" width="250" height="250"   allowTransparency="true">
```

Any ideas on how to get the form to submit and then maybe display the result in the iframe aswell?

Thanks in advance, 
Niall

Comment: What do you get in the mail.php file? are you looking for GET parameters when you are sending POST parameters?

Comment: no, all my parameters are POST

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your page it seems you're closing your iframetag inside the iframe itself.

Your iframe

```
<html>
.
.
.
</table>
</form>
<a href="http://www.texteri.com">Powered by Texteri.com</a>
</iframe>
```

That last `</iframe>` tag should not be there.

It should be like this (at the end)

`<iframe src="http://www.texteri.com/developers/iframe" width="250" height="250"   allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing mistake, it is as you have it above, is that ok?

Comment: If you go directly to your iframe: http://www.texteri.com/developers/iframe/ you see the closing iframe tag at the end, that shouldn't be in there.

Comment: oh god yeah, i see now thanks, but it still is the same problem

Comment: Does [http://www.texteri/developers/iframe/mail.php] exist because if I access that page it says: Network problem

_You tried to access the address [http://www.texteri/developers/iframe/mail.php], which is currently unavailable. Please make sure that the web address (URL) is correctly spelled and punctuated, then try reloading the page._

Comment: I tried manually submitting to that URL and got the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a8634328/public_html/developers/iframe/mail.php on line 12
`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but I've found found the problem- somehow I left out the .com after texteri in www.texteri.com/developers! Thanks for all your help

Comment: maybe post your mail.php code just before and after line 12 here maybe someone can track down the error